# Deploy Firebase Scheduled Function error: "async_hooks_1.AsyncLocalStorage is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am facing some issues to deploy a [Scheduled Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#deploy_a_scheduled_function) to Firebase. This is one of my issues.

At the function deployment, I could capture the (what I think) be the main error reason:

```
Detailed stack trace: TypeError: async_hooks_1.AsyncLocalStorage is not a constructor
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("45 8 * * *")
  .timeZone("America/Sao_Paulo")
  .onRun(() => {
    console.log("Triggering email")
    return null;
  });
```

**Deploy**

```
% firebase deploy --only functions            

=== Deploying to '****'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint ****/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged ****/functions (41.84 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully

The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
        listenReserveCreated(us-central1)

If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify

? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. No
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function scheduledFunction(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        scheduledFunction(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

**Log:**

```
% gcloud functions logs read scheduledFunction
LEVEL  NAME               EXECUTION_ID  TIME_UTC                 LOG
E      scheduledFunction                2023-03-17 12:36:18.077  Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.539  Could not load the function, shutting down.
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:26:17)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/trace.js:6:24)
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538  Detailed stack trace: TypeError: async_hooks_1.AsyncLocalStorage is not a constructor
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538  Is there a syntax error in your code?
       scheduledFunction  csgypxon04g7  2023-03-17 12:36:17.538  Provided module can't be loaded.
E      scheduledFunction                2023-03-17 12:27:24.077  Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging
       scheduledFunction  vfj9lv1lxvmm  2023-03-17 12:27:22.993  Could not load the function, shutting down.
       scheduledFunction  vfj9lv1lxvmm  2023-03-17 12:27:22.992      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
       scheduledFunction  vfj9lv1lxvmm  2023-03-17 12:27:22.992      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:26:17)
       scheduledFunction  vfj9lv1lxvmm  2023-03-17 12:27:22.992      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you're using an outdated version of Node.js. On your logs above, you're still using Node.js v10:

`i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function scheduledFunction(us-central1)...`

According to [Firebase Admin SDK Prerequisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#prerequisites):

> Make sure that your server runs the following depending on which Admin SDK that you use:
>
> - Admin Node.js SDK — Node.js 14+

---

Let me know if the issue still persist after updating your Node.js version.

Comment: i moved to node 16 and compliation passes but now i see the error in the google cloud logs with the same error

Comment: Have you checked your Node version is correctly set up at the Node 16 version in the GCP environment?